# How much time does an ideal capacitor take to discharge?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, time, capacitance

Is it true that an ideal capacitor will take no time to discharge? How can it be possible? In discharging, the excess electrons from negative plate leaves the plate and the postive plate acquires some electrons (not the ones from other plate). The motion of charges has to happen in definite time. How can it (time taken) be zero?

Comment: I'm curious, where did you hear or read that an ideal capacitor will take no time to discharge?

Comment: There is a book that says "When we close the switch the capacitor gets charged immediately. Charging takes no time". Perhaps I should consider changing my study material.

Comment: Eyy boss, pushing ideal circuit theory too far gives nonsense results like a current impulse that changes the voltage across the (ideal) capacitor instantaneously. However, at the foundation of ideal circuit theory are assumptions something like *the rate of change of current and voltage variables is small enough that we can ignore effects that we can't ignore if the rate of change is large enough*. So, one always need to check the solution against those assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it true that an ideal capacitor will take no time to discharge?

No, it's not true.

UPDATE to address some comments (since comments are ethereal):

> Is it true even when capacitor and the connecting wires have no
> resistance?

Eyyboss, does the loop formed by the zero resistance wires and capacitor enclose non-zero area? If so, then there is non-zero self-inductance that limits the rate of change of current. This is outside the realm of ideal circuit theory.

Also, note that discharging an ideal capacitor through an ideal wire (zero resistance), without considerations outside of ideal circuit theory, violates energy conservation, i.e., where did the energy stored in the charged capacitor go?

> If the wires forming the loop are "perfect", then will the shorted
> capacitor never discharge, energy going from purely electrical to
> purely magnetic ....?

jim, there's a non-zero radiation resistance that damps the system, i.e., the system radiates energy away. Related reading: [A Capacitor Paradox](http://physics.princeton.edu/%7Emcdonald/examples/twocaps.pdf)

Comment: Is it true even when capacitor and the connecting wires have no resistance?

Comment: @Eyyboss, does the loop formed by the zero resistance wires and capacitor enclose non-zero area? If so, then there is non-zero self-inductance that limits the rate of change of current. This is outside the realm of ideal circuit theory.

Comment: If the wires forming the loop are "perfect", then will the shorted capacitor never discharge, energy going from purely electrical to purely magnetic ....?

Comment: @jim, there's a non-zero *radiation resistance* that damps the system, i.e., the system radiates energy away. Related reading: [A Capacitor Paradox](http://physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/twocaps.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In circuit theory, an ideal capacitor has no resistance or inductance. It is just an element of an effective model of a circuit. In this context the capacitor will discharge in zero time when shorted.

In a real, nonideal physical situation there will be resistance, inductance, finite speed of electrical perturbation leading to transient effects, and radiation. Each of these effects will slow the discharge.

Comment: Test of your ideal circuit theory intuition: does an ideal capacitor *block DC*?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Do you count a delta function spike of current as DC?

Comment: Goodness no, I'm thinking of an ideal constant current source connected to an ideal capacitor. It's often said that "capacitors block DC". But is that the case? This is unrelated to the OP's question.